# Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas - How to save gas?

Tags: solidity, gas, error

I have a contract that has about ~1.000 lines. But when I try to deploy it, it does not work because of an "out of gas error". I already tried with a limit of the maximum, of 6 million and even 8 million gas, still the same error.

I am working with Remix and would like to know how I can solve it. Due to privacy I cannot post the contract. But I am wondering, **why can I deploy for example the CryptoKitties Contract which has 2x the amount of lines than what I have? and how can I see how much gas the contract needs?** I tried in JavascriptVM with even a gaslimit of 100.000.000 but still not possible. Also in the testnet I use, I tried to limit up the gas limit to 15.000.000, still not possible.

And let's say my contract has 2 parts:
contract Token {}
contract Project {}

**What would happen when I deploy only contract "Project" without the "is Token"? Could I still access Token somehow?**

---

EDIT: When I enable the "Enable Optimization" option in Remix, the deploying works. Why? What is that option?

---